# How to get a table by table name?

Tags: sql

I want to get the table that goes into the from clause through the table name.

```
select * 
from(
SELECT  table_name
FROM    information_schema.tables
WHERE   table_name = 'mTest'
);
```

What I have is 'mTest'.

I want to get the actual mTest table through'mTest'.

Is it not possible with sql?

Comment: Are you just interested in just the name or the actual data in the table? Because I don't understand why you are trying to use a SELECT query to get the table name for the FROM component.

Comment: I want to get the data of a table through the table name.
I have the table name in quotes.
But
" select * from' table name'  " format does not work.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`tableName\`` gives you all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working with SQL Server because of the `information_schema` table stuff. So you can try `sp_executesql` for dynamic statement

```
DECLARE @tablename AS nvarchar(50)
SET @tablename = 'mTest'
DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(500);
SET @query  = 'SELECT * FROM ' +  @tablename;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```